# AVR Atmel MCUs with 12bit ADC and ArduinoIDE support

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, avr, atmel

I am searching for more powerful MCUs than the ATMEGA1284p that I am currently using, in particular I want to have better ADCs and switch from 10 to 12bit resolution. My constraints are the following:

- 12bit ADC
- Low-power during sleep
- Available Arduino bootloader
- ArduinoIDE support but I guess that is the saame as an available Arduino Bootloader

Comment: What do you determine as ‘low power’? There’s a number of Arduino bootloaders depending on the actual microcontroller, so which one do you want? The Arduino IDE supports a wide range of microcontrollers that might fit your broad criteria. You might want to tighten up your specs. I could suggest XMC1100.

Comment: you could use external ADC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the STM32 Nucleo range should provide exactly what you want. The cheapest option the Nucleo f030r8 blows the atmega1284p out of the water in regards to memory, speed and peripherals. It is supported by the Arduino IDE, supports the majority of shields and has a 12bit ADC.